# Django: want to display ValidationError message without showing "Please correct the error below."

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin, django-validation

I have a form raising a ValidationError in admin panel, like this

```
class HistoryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = History
        fields = '__all__'

    def clean(self):
        raise ValidationError("A history error")
```

When the ValidationError is raised, the admin page always showing "Please correct the error below." with the error message "A history error".

Now I want to show the error message "A history error" only without "Please correct the error below.", how can I achieve it?

I want a method without modifying template.

Answer (score 1):

That message comes with the default admin [`change_form.html`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/3c447b108ac70757001171f7a4791f493880bf5b/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_form.html#L47) template. In order to remove it, you'll have to override the `chagne_form.html` template.

Comment: is there a solution that don't need to adjust template

Comment: Unfortunately, No. You have to override it to change the default behaviour. You can just copy-paste the template without that message in you new template. It is quite simple.